# React Syntax Highlighter - [object Object]

Tags: javascript, массивы, reactjs, объекты, redux

```
{
    titleName: "Creating Your First JavaScript",
    heading: 'Ready. Set. JavaScript!',
    iconName: faDotCircle,
    description: [
        `
        <h2 class="title_description">Let’s start</h2>
        With the basics and add some JavaScript to a web page. On the web, JavaScript code
        ${
            <SyntaxHighlighter language="javascript" style={docco}>
            <pre>
                <code>&lt;nav class=&quot;main-navigation&quot;&gt;
                    &lt;ul&gt;
                        &lt;li&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;/&quot;&gt;Home&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
                        &lt;li&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;about.html&quot;&gt;About Us&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
                        &lt;li&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;contact.html&quot;&gt;Contact Us&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
                    &lt;/ul&gt;
                &lt;/nav&gt;
               </code>
           </pre>
          </SyntaxHighlighter>
        }
      `
    ],
},
```

Я использовал  и  для отображения некоторых фрагментов кода на https://ibb.co/JsmscSN. Я решил использовать пакет npm React Syntax Highlighter для отображения цвета синтаксиса, но я получаю [object Object] https://ibb.co/c1RDSwK

Comment: в данном случае идет попытка вставить в строку компонент `react`, который действительно является объекта.

Comment: Как мне исправить данную проблему?

Comment: переписать код, который использует данных объект чтобы компонент с `SyntaxHighlighter` отдельно передавался, а не в качестве куска строки. Либо смотреть в сторону рендера компонента в строку, которую и вставлять